# I need to print the True values excluding Nan in a list in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I need to print the True values excluding NaN in a list in pandas dataframe.

```
dfa.where(dfa['Group']=='|Demographics')['Group']
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want `dfa.loc[dfa['Group']=='|Demographics', 'Group']`? If you only want the boolean array, simply use: `dfa['Group']=='|Demographics'`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need is

```
dfa[~dfa["Group"].isin(["|Demographics"]).isnull()]
```

The `isnull()` finds the `nan` values of your condition, but the `~` at the beginning negates this, so yields non nan values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
dfa1 = np.where ((dfa['Group']=='|Demographics') & (dfa['Group'] !=np.NaN)), dfa['Group'],'')

dfa1
```

Comment: quick and good support